# PHP issue with checkbox value

Tags: php, html

I have this PHP code:

```php
function makeTable($data){
    $ordered = array_map(function($day) {
        return array_keys($day);
    }, $data);

    $headers = array_map(function($a) {
        return "<th>$a</th>";
    }, array_keys($ordered));

    $max_indice = max( array_map(function($day) {
        return count($day) - 1;
    }, $ordered) );


    $rows = array_map(function($i) use ($ordered) {
        return '<tr>' . join( array_map(function($day) use ($i) {
            return '<td><input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="' . $i . '" />' . $day[$i] . '</td>';
        }, $ordered)) . '</tr>';
    }, range(0, $max_indice));
    echo "<table border='1'>".join($headers)."<tbody>".join($rows)."</tbody></table>";
}

makeTable($datesAvailableArray);
```

What this function does, it takes my array of `$datesAvailableArray`:

```php
Array
(
    [Saturday] => Array
    (
        [11:00am] => 0
        [12:00pm] => 0
        [1:00pm] => 0
        [2:00pm] => 0
        [3:00pm] => 0
        [4:00pm] => 0
        [5:00pm] => 0
    )

    [Sunday] => Array
    (
        [11:00am] => 0
        [12:00pm] => 0
        [1:00pm] => 0
        [2:00pm] => 0
        [3:00pm] => 0
        [4:00pm] => 0
        [5:00pm] => 0
    )

    [Monday] => Array
    (
        [11:00am] => 0
        [12:00pm] => 0
        [1:00pm] => 0
        [2:00pm] => 0
        [3:00pm] => 0
        [4:00pm] => 0
        [5:00pm] => 0
    )

    [Tuesday] => Array
    (
        [11:00am] => 0
        [12:00pm] => 0
        [1:00pm] => 0
        [2:00pm] => 0
        [3:00pm] => 0
        [4:00pm] => 0
        [5:00pm] => 0
    )

    [Wednesday] => Array
    (
        [11:00am] => 0
        [12:00pm] => 0
        [1:00pm] => 0
        [2:00pm] => 0
        [3:00pm] => 0
        [4:00pm] => 0
        [5:00pm] => 0
    )

    [Thursday] => Array
    (
        [11:00am] => 0
        [12:00pm] => 0
        [1:00pm] => 0
        [2:00pm] => 0
        [3:00pm] => 0
        [4:00pm] => 0
        [5:00pm] => 0
    )

    [Friday] => Array
    (
        [11:00am] => 0
        [12:00pm] => 0
        [1:00pm] => 0
        [2:00pm] => 0
        [3:00pm] => 0
        [4:00pm] => 0
        [5:00pm] => 0
    )
)
```

and makes this html table:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Saturday November 15th
            </th>
            <th>
                Sunday November 16th
            </th>
            <th>
                Monday November 17th
            </th>
            <th>
                Tuesday November 18th
            </th>
            <th>
                Wednesday November 19th
            </th>
            <th>
                Thursday November 20th
            </th>
            <th>
                Friday November 21st
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="0">
                11:00am
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="0">
                11:00am
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="0">
                11:00am
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="0">
                11:00am
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="0">
                11:00am
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="0">
                11:00am
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="0">
                11:00am
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="1">
                12:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="1">
                12:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="1">
                12:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="1">
                12:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="1">
                12:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="1">
                12:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="1">
                12:00pm
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="2">
                1:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="2">
                1:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="2">
                1:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="2">
                1:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="2">
                1:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="2">
                1:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="2">
                1:00pm
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="3">
                2:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="3">
                2:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="3">
                2:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="3">
                2:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="3">
                2:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="3">
                2:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="3">
                2:00pm
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="4">
                3:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="4">
                3:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="4">
                3:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="4">
                3:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="4">
                3:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="4">
                3:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="4">
                3:00pm
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="5">
                4:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="5">
                4:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="5">
                4:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="5">
                4:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="5">
                4:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="5">
                4:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="5">
                4:00pm
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="6">
                5:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="6">
                5:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="6">
                5:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="6">
                5:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="6">
                5:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="6">
                5:00pm
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="6">
                5:00pm
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is put the heading date as the checkbox value. Is this possible with this code?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It is unclear what the question is. i.e. have you simply tried to do it and see what happens?

Comment: Err. Replace `value="0"` with `value="the data you want"`. (And please make better use of whitespace to format you code)

Comment: You have 2 `<tbody>` sections I am sure you intended to have a `<thead>` and then a `<tbody>`

Comment: If I change my checkbox value to $day[$i] I would get the time I am looking to add the date to the checkbox...does that make sense?

Comment: the id would be different as the date and time is different for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are going to want to change your `$datesAvailableArray` so that it contains an actual dates.
[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings are an excellent format.

```
$datesAvailableArray = array(
    'Saturday' => array(
        '2014-11-14T11:00:00Z',
        '2014-11-14T12:00:00Z',
        '2014-11-14T13:00:00Z',
        '2014-11-14T14:00:00Z'
    ),
    'Sunday' => array(
        '2014-11-15T11:00:00Z',
        '2014-11-15T12:00:00Z',
        '2014-11-15T13:00:00Z',
        '2014-11-15T14:00:00Z'
    )
);
```

Now that we have date strings we can create DateTime objects that we use to format the date:

```
$saturday_1100 = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2014-11-14T11:00:00Z');
$saturday_1100->format('g:ia'); // 11:00am
```

In our case we are using the [DateTimeImmutable class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) since we don't want to change the dates after they are created.

So lets change our `makeTable` function to use our new friend `DateTimeImmutable`:

```
function makeTable($data) {

    $headers = array_map(function($a) {
        return "<th>$a</th>";
    }, array_keys($data));

    $max_indice = max( array_map(function($day) {
        return count($day) - 1;
    }, $data) );

    // Create a new array where we group by hour
    $rows = array_map(function($i) use ($data) {
        // create each hour
        return '<tr>' . join( array_map(function($day) use ($i){
            $ts = isset($day[$i]) ? DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $day[$i]) : null;
            if ($ts){
                $label = '<label for="datetime">'.$ts->format('g:ia').'</label>';
                $input = vsprintf ( 
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="%s" value="%s" />',
                    array(
                        'datetime_'. $ts->getTimestamp(), // ID
                        $ts->format('c')  // Value
                    )
                );
                return '<td>' . $label . $input . '<td>';
            } else {
                return '<td></td>';
            }
        }, $data)) . '</tr>';
    }, range(0, $max_indice));

    // Don´t get rid of the thead element. 
    // It tells the browser that your table is a real table containing data and not just a crappy layout.
    return "
    <table>
        <caption>My Table</caption>
        <thead>".join($headers,'\n')."</thead>
        <tbody>".join($rows, '\n')."</tbody>
    </table>";
}
```

`echo makeTable( $datesAvailableArray );` Will give us something like this:

```
<table>
  <caption>
    My Table
  </caption>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="datetime">11:00am</label><input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime_1415962800" value="2014-11-14T11:00:00+00:00" /></td>
      <td><label for="datetime">11:00am</label><input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime_1416049200" value="2014-11-15T11:00:00+00:00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="datetime">12:00pm</label><input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime_1415966400" value="2014-11-14T12:00:00+00:00" /></td>
      <td><label for="datetime">12:00pm</label><input type="checkbox" name="datetime" id="datetime_1416052800" value="2014-11-15T12:00:00+00:00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- MORE ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Summary:

We have unique values for the input id. The value that we send when posting this form is a ISO-8601 date string. 
We also have wrapped our hour text in `<label>` tags with a for attribute which is good for accessibility.